# Cocoa - Save profile image/avatar (png) to mysql database?

Tags: database, image, ipad, storage

Key point here:

- This is my first game, which means, I am new to develop iOS games.
- My game is using game center.
- From what I know, you can sign in game center on different devices, for example sign in from: UserA's iPad, or sign in from userB's iPad, or maybe sign in from userC's iPhone, thus I think I must store the profile image(avatar) to web(online) database (I am using mysql database, for the moment)
- The profile image size is not that huge(150x200 pixels, png format), so I am thinking, store as BLOB type.

Questions:

1. Is it good to store the image as BLOB type **in my case**? (I know, most of you would probably say that store image path would be better, that's why I highlight the "in my case", what I mean is that, I must assume the player might/can sign in from different devices)
2. How to store PNG image to MySQL database? (FYI: Currently I use json(specifically: json-framework) for sending-and-receiving data, like player's username, ability, level, job from database to the device)

If you have any better ideas of storing the profile image or data, please share with me.